# loopback relation to same model

Tags: node.js, loopbackjs

I have a FollowMap as follows

```
{
      "name": "FollowMap",
      .
      .
      .
      "relations": {
        "follower_acc": {
          "type": "belongsTo",
          "model": "Account",
          "foreignKey": "follower_id"
        },
        "following_acc": {
          "type": "belongsTo",
          "model": "Account",
          "foreignKey": "following_id"
        }
      }
    }
```

I want to build a relation to my Account model, so I can get one users follower & following list, the Account model is as follows;

```
{
  "name": "Account",
  .
  .
  .
    "followers": {
      "type": "hasMany",
      "model": "FollowMap",
      "foreignKey": "following_id"
    },
    "following": {
      "type": "hasMany",
      "model": "FollowMap",
      "foreignKey": "follower_id"
    }
  }
}
```

From the relation, I can fetch a Account's follower and following count however, I can't fetch the follower and following Account list from these relations. I hope it's clear.

Answer (score 1):

I know this issue is maybe outdated, but for those who are still looking for the solution, i'll give mine. I wanted to do implement the publisher/subscriber relation between the profils entities in my database.

The most obvious way to do it is with the **hasAndBelongsToMany** relation, but strangely you cannot change the foreignKey used in model: it means you cannot declare **"publishedId"** and **"subscriberId"** to be used as foreign keys referencing a Profil entity.

You have to declare manually the third table used to reference those 2 foreign keys.

My working example for this third table:

```
//common/models/subscribing.json
{
  "name": "Subscribing",
  "base": "PersistedModel",
  "idInjection": true,
  "options": {
    "validateUpsert": true
  },
  "properties": {},
  "validations": [],
  "relations": {
    "subscriber": {
      "type": "belongsTo",
      "model": "Profil",
      "as": "subscriber"
    },
    "publisher": {
      "type": "belongsTo",
      "model": "Profil",
      "as": "publisher"
    }
  },
  "acls": [],
  "methods": {}
}
```

And my Profil entity related to itself through the Subscribings table:

```
//common/models/profil.json
{
  "name": "Profil",
  "base": "PersistedModel",
  "idInjection": true,
  "options": {
    "validateUpsert": true
  },
  "properties": {
    "name": {
      "type": "string",
      "required": true
    }
  },
  "validations": [],
  "relations": {
    "followers": {
      "type": "hasMany",
      "model": "Profil",
      "foreignKey": "publisherId",
      "keyThrough": "subscriberId",
      "through": "Subscribing"
    },
    "subscribings": {
      "type": "hasMany",
      "model": "Profil",
      "foreignKey": "subscriberId",
      "keyThrough": "publisherId",
      "through": "Subscribing"
    }
  },
  "acls": [],
  "methods": {}
}
```